# Google DataStream character varying not being replicated

Tags: postgresql, cdc, google-datastream

I have setup Google DataStream to replicate data from PostgresSQL using CDC. It works fine, but I have noticed that all character varying columns are not being replicated. I can see them in the source schema, but the destination table that been created it doesn't have that column at all.

Comment: Hi @Akram, did you excluded the data while configuring information about the source database as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/create-a-stream#configuresourcedb)?

Answer (score 0):

Akram - if I am not mistaken you will see the new column only AFTER you add some data to that column. The same applies to new tables created in source DB (in case you select the option to replicate all new tables when setting up replication publication in PostgreSQL)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Datastream for Postgresql has "Public preview" status and does not yet support the replication of "character varying []" (and if I'm not mistaken "citex" as well) Postgresql data types.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).